# simple python program doesnt run. shows intendent error

Tags: python, indentation

I'm trying to fix a problem like if a number is odd or even. this is a simple program  to find if a number is odd or even

```
x=input("enter x")
if x%2==0:
  print "even"
else
  print "odd"
```

shows indented error in line 3.
plz help

Comment: add `:` after `else` too

Comment: do `int(input("enter x"))` to cast to int

Comment: @Chengzhi no need here to cast into int. Python interpreter will automatically take a number here.

Comment: @omniverse10 only in Python 2, where you shouldn't really be using `input` anyway because it calls `eval()`. In python 3 it will be a string. OP hasn't tagged with a version.

Comment: `print` without parentheses seems to be a strong indicator for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

**okay, first of all -** 
you haven't formatted your code properly. Use the shortcut ctrl+K to do so when you're posting a question. I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
x = input("Enter X")
if x % 2 == 0:
    print "Even"
else:
    print "Odd"
```

Comment: Why the unneeded parentheses? `if x % 2 == 0:` is enough.

Comment: you're right, I edited the answer. I generally use parenthesis for clarity on my part but it does break PEP 8 conventions.